# How can I change the default python3 path in MAC cmd?

Tags: python, macos

My Mac has contained multiple python versions so that I would like to fix one as my default python.

In the current, it has set the path of anaconda python. I have stopped to use the anaconda-python.
[image: anaconda_python]

And I would like to change the python3 as default following with path:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

How can I do this?

Hope:

- python3 as default that path
- jupyter notebook would follow that path
- pip3 install package would follow that path

Answer (score 1):

You can change the path to this by editing the .bashrc file

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin/python3:${PATH}"
```

Comment: I followed your approach, but `which python3` / `which python` still is showing the path of anaconda

Comment: My bad you need to append the path at the start, I have edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

Update your environment variable PATH to include your required python path. Append the python path in the beginning of the environment variable PATH, so that first it'll look in that path.

You need to update that in .bash_profile file. For that go to the root path and look for the mentioned file. Run ls-a to check whether the file is present.

```
cd ~
ls -a
```

Open the file

```
vi .bash_profile
```

Add below commands in the file (press i to go into insert mode)

```
# Setting PATH for Python
export PATH={ur path}:$PATH
```

(Save the file by pressing :wq)

Check whether the update is made by running

```
echo $PATH
```

Comment: I have tried your approach, `echo $PATH` is showing the new path I set but which python3 / which python still is showing the path of anaconda

Comment: You've appended the path in the beginning of PATH variable right? Please append in beginning and let me know the output of echo $PATH